# Parsing Ruby hash literal using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, hash

I need to take raw client text in a web form and send it back to a Tomcat servlet as JSON. For legacy reasons, this input may be formatted as a Ruby hash. I also cannot force my clients to convert their existing Ruby formatted inputs over to JSON. I could write a custom parser, but I wanted to see if a JavaScript based solution existed that would allow me to determine if a blob of text is a Ruby hash and, if so, convert it into JSON.

Comment: can not use `object.to_json`?

Comment: I believe that's a Rails thing, no?

Comment: What do you mean by "a Ruby hash"? Do you mean a hash literal? JSON is a data serialization format; a Ruby hash literal is a programming construct and doesn't have anything like the same constraints as JSON.`{ class Foo; end => 2**Float::INFINITY }` is a perfectly valid hash literal in Ruby.

Comment: The input I'm referring to would be objects that were serialized out in, from what little of I know of Ruby, the Ruby hash format.

Comment: Ruby hash can contain any Ruby object - when you serialize a hash to string using `to_s` method, you can get something like `{:a=>5, "asdasd"=>nil, :b=>2016-02-01 10:18:43 +0100}`. You definitely can't parse that, even using Ruby, as, as Jordan already said, that's not a serialization format as JSON is. However, you might write something which would cover a _subset_ of it, for example, constraining the keys and values to strings and/or numbers. You need to clarify that first, in order to proceed.

Answer (score -1):

JSON is a Ruby standard library. You've to just require it:

```
require 'json'

data = {:hello => "goodbye"}
p data.to_json #=> "{\"hello\":\"goodbye\"}"
```

Ref: [Generating JSON](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Generating+JSON)

Comment: Your solution utilizes Ruby which I do not have access to.