# Needing an alternative to eval() and better way for replacing string values

Tags: javascript, json

The API i'm working with responds back with a base64 encoded ruby hash (similar to a json object, but specifically for ruby) that has been converted to a string before base64 encoding

From javascript upon retrieving the encoded string, when decoded I get a string in the same shape as the ruby string it originated as on the server

```
// Decoded example String
"{:example=>'string',:another_example=>'string'}"
```

I am able to parse out the ruby string to a JSON object using string replace and eval() but I know eval() is evil. Also, there is no way to handle any other key value pairs that may pop up in the future.

How should this be re written with no eval and no direct string replacements?

```
var storedToken = base64url.decode(window.localStorage.authtoken).replace(':example=>', 'example:').replace(':another_example=>', 'another_example:')
var parsedTokenString = JSON.stringify(eval('(' + storedToken + ')'))
var newJsonObject = JSON.parse(parsedTokenString)
```

Comment: @SiddharthNand Nothing similar here more than only the title

Comment: changed title just in case.

Comment: If server is under your control, convert it to json by `.to_json` in `json` package should be a better idea.

Comment: This is the duplicate to, but that question has no answer yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109343/parsing-ruby-hash-literal-using-javascript

Comment: If you updated your string replace to double-quote the property names and convert the values' single quotes to double quotes I think you would have valid JSON that you could then pass directly to `JSON.parse()` without needing `eval()`. Note that in the code you already have the `.stringify()` and `.parse()` are redundant, because the `eval()` will have already returned the desired object. (As an aside, [there is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).)

Comment: @nnnnnn no, string with single quote wrapped is not a valid json

Comment: So is your question "How do I convert a string like `"{:example=>'string',:another_example=>'string'}"` to valid JSON"?

Comment: @nnnnnn—well, there is the built-in [*JSON* Object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-json-object). ;-)

Comment: @RobG - I know you know that I know you know what I meant, but anyway...that doesn't invalidate my previous comment because it's not *a* JSON object, it's *the* JSON object.

Comment: @nnnnnn—yep. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Replace and then `JSON.parse`:

```js
 const storedToken = "{:example=>'string',:another_example=>'string'}";
 
 const json = storedToken
   .replace(/:(\w+)/g, '"$1"')
   .replace(/=>/g, ':')
   .replace(/'/g, '"');

const obj = JSON.parse(json)

console.log(obj);
```

You will probably want to tighten this up to avoid things breaking when the string values contain things like `:foo` or escaped single quotes.

However, as mentioned in other answers and comments, you should really change the server to return JSON, which is easy enough with Ruby's `to_json`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a string like:

```
"{:example=>'string',:another_example=>'string'}"
```

that you'd like to convert to an object like (using JSON):

```
'{":example":"string", ":another_example":"string"}'
```

It's unclear to me if the colon before `:example` is part of the property name or a token indicating a property name, I've assumed it's part of the name (but that's easy to modify).

A regular expression might be used, however if the tokens are:

```
{   start of notation
=>  property name, value separator
,   property/value pair separator
}   end of notation
```

Then a simple parser/formatter might be something like:

```js
function stringToJSON(s) {

  var resultText = '';
  var tokens = {
    '{' : '{',  // token: replacement 
    '=>': ':',
    ',' : ',',
    '}' : '}'
  };
  var multiTokens = {
    '=': '=>' // token start: full token
  };
  var buff = '';

  // Process each character
  for (var i = 0, iLen = s.length; i < iLen; i++) {

    // Collect characters and see if they match a token
    buff = s[i];

    // Deal with possible multi-character tokens
    if (buff in multiTokens) {

      // Check with next character and add to buff if creates a token
      // Also increment i as using next character
      if ((buff + s[i + 1]) in tokens) {
        buff += s[++i];
      }
    }

    // Now check in tokens
    if (buff in tokens) {
      // Tokens are always surrounded by ", except for first { and last }
      // but deal with those at the end
      resultText += '"' + tokens[buff] + '"';

      // Otherwise, deal with single characters
    } else {

      // Single quotes not allowed
      if (buff == "'") buff = '';

      // Add buff to result
      resultText += buff;
    }
  }
  // Remove leading and trailing "
  return resultText.replace(/^\"|\"$/g, '');
}

var s = "{:example=>'string',:another_example=>'string'}";

console.log(stringToJSON(s));

// Convert to object
console.log(JSON.parse(stringToJSON(s)));
```

Your string notation might be more complex, but I think you get the gist of it. You may need to trim whitespace around tokens, but since the property names aren't surrounded by quotes it's hard to know what to keep and what to throw away. You could include tokens in the data by quoting, then throwing away the quote character, e.g.:

```
\=>
```

could be treated as the literal "=>", not a token.

More tokens and processing steps can be added fairly easily. The multi-character tokens can get interesting, especially if you go to 3 or for characters.

Array methods and regular expressions can be used for token matching and processing, however I think loops are a good place to start to get the logic sorted, sugar can be added later.